# Badge page formatting is inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

When viewing the awards of the [Announcer badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57?page=3), the display has a glitch in it when viewed in Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 m and/or Firefox 22. Some entries are displayed in a tabular format, while others are displayed "ragged right":

[image]

This may also be the case with other, similarly-awarded, pages (like [Booster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/58/booster), [Publicist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/publicist), and maybe others).

Comment: doesn't happen here; firefox 19.0.2.  every listing is flush left.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Even across all the pages? I've added a browser-specific mention to the post, but I see the same problem in Firefox 22 (portable).

Comment: all 7 pages.  (somehow i figured it would be a good idea to check thoroughly.  i'll look at some other badge pages, just to be sure, and report back.)

Comment: okay, have looked at more pages, a few in each general category.  not all pages are formatted the same, but on every page, the formatting is consistent.  from this desk, it looks like a browser (possibly browser version) issue.  good luck.  (my current dilemma is why on one machine a pdf file is launched by `texdoc` to `xpdf`, and on another, to acrobat reader.  it's driving me to distraction!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be fixed in the next deployment.

Comment: When are these deployments scheduled for in general?

Comment: We deploy at will, normally multiple times a day, but not for minor CSS fixes.

Comment: @Werner there's no need, I've pushed a fix just now.